# wxpython textctrl change caret colour

Tags: colors, wxpython, caret, textctrl

I'm using a wxpython textctrl & would like to hide the caret. After a lot of searching it would appear that the best approach would be to simply change it's colour to white. However I can not work out how to do this.

I found the following info:

SetCaretForeground(fore)

Sets the foreground color of the caret. The parameter fore is a wxColour object, a #RRGGBB string, or a color spec like "white". Returns None.

from here: http://www.yellowbrain.com/stc/caret.html#setfg

The code for my current textctrl is below. Any help would be appreciated.

```
self.control = wx.TextCtrl(self, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE | wx.TE_READONLY | wx.HSCROLL)
```

Clinton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a `wx.TextCtrl` and the link you give is for a `wx.StyledTextCtrl`.  These are completely different animals, and the `wx.StyledTextCtrl` has a lot more functionality than the simple `wx.TextCtrl`.

I don't think there's a way to set the caret color in an ordinary `wx.TextCtrl`.

Comment: Hi Tom10, thanks for the reply. I was obviously getting comletely confused. Will have to look at changing the textctrl I'm using. Thanks again.